# Possible Safari Bug? Fixed div inside of relative div doesn't animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have some JQuery that works fine in FF and Chrome but I noticed it isn't working in Safari 6.1 on a mac. Essentially it's a container set to `position:relative` with a box inside set to `position:fixed`. When I try to animate it left, the container moves but not the fixed element. Upon further testing, a box does animate left if it's set to `relative` and again if it's `fixed` but not a combination of the two. I need this to be `fixed` so setting it to `absolute` will not help. AGAIN this works fine in FF and Chrome.

If you have Safari check out this fiddle and let me know if anyone has experienced this:

**EDIT**

I forgot this is actually using `.css` instead of `.animate` and it's working on `$(window).scroll(function()"`. Updated fiddle below :

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eqATT/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked on Safari and surprisingly, it doesn't work with fixed value. So, here's my solution. Why don't you add .box along with $this. For example:

```
$(".container").click(function(){
$('.box', this).animate({"left": "-100px"});
});
```

This way, it works on all the browsers. A quick hack for safari, I would say.

Comment: Small error here. `this` is a keyword and can't be a string. You'd need to do `$('.box', this)`

Comment: @DhirajShah yeah this does work. Unfortunately I just realized im actually not using `.animate` but `.css` because I'm moving this on scroll. Here is an updated fiddle to show how it's actually supposed to work. I'm going to update my question too (works in chrome, not in safari): [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eqATT/6/)

Comment: @DhirajShah I got it, I have to use `$(".container, .box")` and it will work. I'm going to check this off because you technically did answer my original question and you got me to this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would say that this is more a bug in FF and Chrome than in Safari. Fixed position is positioning relative to the viewport. If you were to add `left`/`top` values to `.box`, you'll see the same behavior in FF and Chrome.

```
.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: black;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqATT/5/)